# TimeConvert JavaScript function on Coderbyte

Tags: javascript, function

I am doing a challenge on Coderbyte and I would be grateful for any advice on my question:

I know there is an easier way to solve this(which I found later):

```
function TimeConvert(num) { 
  var hours = Math.floor(num / 60);  
  var minutes = num % 60;
  return hours + ":" + minutes; 
  }
```

...so TimeConvert(123); would be 2:3

I know my answer is more complicated but why is the way I attempted to answer this question not working? What am I missing? It just returns 0:00 for any number entered:

```
function TimeConvert(num) { 
    var hours=0;
    var minutes=0;

    for(var i=0; i<=num; i+=60) {//loop through number every 60
        if(num[i]>=60) { //for every 60 add 1 hour
            hours+=1;
        }else if(num[i]<60){
            minutes=num[i];
        }
    }

  var newMinute=0;
    if (minutes<10){
            newMinutes="0"+minutes;
        }else if(minutes>10){
            newMinutes=minutes;
        }

    return(hours + ":" + newMinutes);          
}
```

Thanks guys!^^

Comment: Your problem is that you are making datetime calculations without using `Date()` object. You've got methods for this in javascript but you are making loops and all crazy things to achieve something that exists. You can start with this: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manipulate-time-and-date-values-with-javascripts-date-object/ Or if this is very complicated for you, you can use the Moment.js library that makes datetime things easier. http://momentjs.com

Comment: @MarcosPérezGudem i don't think that is the issue. Check my answer below.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGudem I know there are simpler ways to solve this, but I am new with JavaScript. I was to figure out how I can create a solution with my current thinking. I believe this will help me in the long run as a developer and helps practice my problem solving skill. :)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGudem *want not was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you! I actually figured out two ways to solve this. First, I should iterate by 1, not 60, and in the first if statement I need to subtract by 60 for every iteration as so:

```
function TimeConvert(num) { 
    var hours=0;
    var minutes=0;

    for(var i=0; i<=num; i++) {
        if(num>=60) { //for every 60 add 1 hour
            hours+=1;
            num-=60;//makes sure that the loop goes every 60
        }else if(num<60){
            minutes=num;
        }
    }
```

//below not necessary for Coderbyte, added for styling reasons. Same for second answer

```
    var newMinute=0;
    if (minutes<10){
            newMinutes="0"+minutes;
    }else if(minutes>10){
            newMinutes=minutes;
    }
```

//write minutes not newMinutes(for Coderbyte). Same for second answer.

```
  return(hours + ":" + newMinutes); 
  }
```

And I figured how to do this with a while loop:

```
function TimeConvert(num) { 
    var hours=0;
    var minutes=0;
    var newMinutes=0;

    while(num>=60) {
        hours+=1;
        num-=60;
    }

    if(num<60){
      minutes=num;
    }

    if (minutes<10){
      newMinutes="0"+minutes;
    }else if(minutes>10){
      newMinutes=minutes;
    }

    return(hours + ":" + newMinutes);          
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why you doin `num[i]>=60`? All you need to check is `num>=60` and `num<60`. `num[i]` will always be an undefined value and num is not a string. (If it would have been a string it num[i] will print the character corresponding to that index.) So you need to compare `num` and not `num[i]`.

```
    function TimeConvert(num) { 
    var hours=0;
    var minutes=0;
    var times = num;
    for(var i=0; i<times; i+=60) {//loop through number every 60
        if(num>=60) { //for every 60 add 1 hour
            hours+=1;
            num -= 60;
        }else if(num<60){
            minutes=num;
        }
    }

  var newMinute=0;
    if (minutes<10){
            newMinutes="0"+minutes;
        }else if(minutes>10){
            newMinutes=minutes;
        }

    return(hours + ":" + newMinutes);          
}

console.log(TimeConvert(123));
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/L5g4fbcf/1/)

Comment: thank you @void for clearing the num issue out. I was confused about num and num[i], and you clarified something for me that I already knew but wasn't sticking yet. But even when I applied this change, the function still didn't work right. I figured out the problem and two solutions below. ^^

Comment: @Masha i think that the function is working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/L5g4fbcf/.

Comment: Actually when you enter in 123 it gives 3:00. It should be 2:03

Comment: @Masha oh yes, check the updated answer and updated fiddle :)

Comment: Is it the same link because I'm getting the same answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can also include ES6 [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in addition to [Math.floor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) for a one-line return statement.

```
function TimeConvert(num) { 
  return `${Math.floor(num/60)}:${num%60}`; 
}
```